# jquery scrollto not working after added to cms theme

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I am trying to get my jquery scrollto function to work and it doesn't seem to have any easing or animation. I think because I am using drupal my wrappers are all messed up cause I built it with no cms and it worked and then when I added it to drupal the theme and tpl.php files added alot of wrappers that werent there and it broke the script.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#nav a').click(function() {
    var target = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
    $('body').scrollTo($(target), 500, {'axis':'y'});
    return false;
  });

});
```

Thats the code I am using 
Here's the link where the issue is ?

The fragment link wrks but I dont think the scrollto is finding the element.

Let me know if I can clarify in any way thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I think my css selector is prob wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this wrapper function instead of the document ready function.  This let's drupal know that you are using jQuery and not some other javascript library.  The site that you linked us to has an error that says the $ is not a function.  That's because either jQuery isn't loading or Drupal doesn't know it's jQuery.

```
(function ($) {

   // Your Code

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: cool thanks I forgot that changed

Answer (score 1):

jsheffers is right. I would also use Drupal.behaviours..

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/better-understanding-of-behaviours-of-drupal-7

Also, I noticed you are loading jQuery v1.7.1 on top of the default jQuery loaded by Drupal:

http://dept-art.com/sites/all/themes/adaptivetheme/at_core/scripts/jquery-1.js

That could be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
        $('body').scrollTo($(target), 500, {'axis':'y'});
    });
});
```